# memory releasing in C++(VS2008)

Tags: c++

Look at the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class Buf
{
public:
    Buf(size_t size)
    {
        _storage.reserve(size);
    }
    ~Buf()
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        _storage.swap( temp );//release memory
    }
    vector<int> _storage;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while( ++i < 10000)
    {       
        Buf *buf = new Buf(100000);
        delete buf;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I run it in debug mode(VS2008):when I set a break point in the line

```
//main function
int i = 0;
```

I find that the Process MyProgram.exe occupies about 300KB memory in Windows Task Manager.When I set a break point in the line

```
return 0;
```

The Process MyProgram.exe occupies about 700KB in Windows Task Manager.

My question is :why the memory that the program occupies increased?I think I have release the memory exactly~Why?

Comment: Why don't you use clear method for _storage?

Comment: @besworland clear method wouldn't release the memory~it just clear the elements in the container~

Comment: clear method: all the elements of the vector are dropped: their destructors are called, and then they are removed from the vector container, leaving the container with a size of 0.

Comment: Funny, clear function really depends on compiler. You are right!

Comment: The destructor of Buf is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @JurajBlaho You are right ~Thanks for your answer~

Answer (score 3):

Standard memory allocator will not (usually) release memory to OS when you deallocate it. Instead it will keep it for subsequent allocations for your process.

Thus you don't see memory ussage decrease in TM even though you deallocated it.

Answer (score 3):

The OS/Debug environment might employ optimization techniques and your memory releasing probably just returns it to pool; the actual memory release probably occurs on program termination